# View's contentDescription does not work correctly with TextToSpeech

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text-to-speech

I work with TextToSpeech and adding "android:contentDescription="@string/custom_button" for ImageButton in xml, reads the value from "@string/custom_button" and adds another "button" in speech.

EG:

"@string/custom_button" = "Custom Button" mapped for mentiond ImageButton, is read as "Custom Button button". There is no text in this button. Id is much different.

How to get rid ot this last "button". It refers to all views read by TextToSpeech.

Answer (score 1):

From my work/research with accessibility, Android automatically adds "button' to the end of talk back for buttons. I could not find any documentation breaking now accessibility to the coding level, but from what i gather they probably add this in the case the developer forgets to indicate in the content description that the the user has clicked a button. There is nothing you can do to remove android's addition of the word button. What you can do is remove it from you custom description so that is only says "Custom". Hope this helps.